# Reduce on tuples

Tags: scala

I have the following type: `val l:Seq[(List[Int],Set[Int])] = ...`

I am trying to reduce it as follows:

```
l.reduceLeft {  
    case ((a1,b1),(a2,b2)) => if((b1 & b2).nomEmpty) ((a1:::a2),(b1 | b2)) else (a1,b1) }
```

I get the following:

```
error:Expression of type (List[Int],Set[Int]) doesn't conform to expected type B_
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a meta post related to this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356907/unaccepting-answer-due-to-serial-voting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of `reduceLeft` looks like this:

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

`B` is our accumulator and return type. In order for this to compile, we need to help the compiler out a bit and tell it what type we want it to be:

```
l.reduceLeft[(List[Int], Set[Int])] {
  case ((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) => if ((b1 & b2).nonEmpty) (a1 ::: a2, b1 | b2) else (a1, b1)
}
```